# How to set a background image in Unity?

Tags: unity

I am trying to create a game on Unity but I am still learning. I want to make a start menu, and I want to set a background image. Then, I will add "Play" or "Exit" buttons on top of this image.

How can I do that?

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Questions about "**how to get started**", "what to learn next", or "which technology to use" are offtopic for this site. Please check the [help](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting.

Comment: The official Unity tutorials on their website are absolutely wonderful! They'll tell you everything you need to get started.

Comment: @Soapy This is no such question. It describes a specific problem with  specific solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You must engineer your background just like any other object in your scene.

Create a **Quad**, place it behind all your other GameObjects, orientate it towards the camera and enlarge it to cover the whole view. Then add your background **Sprite** to the **Quad**.